# Calculating limit with Riemann sum

Tags: calculus, limits, riemann-sum

Question: Compute $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\log\left(\dfrac{n!}{n^n}\right)$.

I am supposed to "Manipulate the limit to look like a Riemann sum."
I've tried to split up $\log(\frac{n!}{n^n})$ into $\log(\frac 1n)+\log(\frac 2n)...\log(\frac nn)$ but I don't know where to go from here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are obviously on the right track! Now transform this into an integral and solve it!

Comment: How do I get the sum into the form of an integral though?

Comment: This is a “Riemann Sum” you needed. The limit is a Riemann integral. Compute the integral is equivalent to calculate this limit. Totally a translation of definitions.

Comment: But I am not sure which function's integral this sum is corresponding to?

Comment: Look at the definition of Riemann integral and compare to your expression in question. Of course there is a uniformly designated infinitesimally small interval. Look carefully.

Comment: How would I get the sum into an integral? There is no infinitesimally small interval for each rectangle under the curve

Comment: Is the function log(x) then? and then the sum adds up across (0,1]?

Comment: Correct.$ $ $ $ $ $ :)